# Regression Model with data

Tags: regression, descriptive-statistics

[image: Regression Model]

I do not know how to fit the data into a regression model. Can someone help me get started on how to formulate the model so i can continue my calculation of estimates?

Answer (score 0):

The coefficients can be estimated by taking

$$\hat{\beta_0}=\bar{y}-\hat{\beta_1}\bar{x}$$

and

$$\hat{\beta_1}=\frac{SS_{xy}}{SS_{xx}}=\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2}$$

Can you go from here?

Comment: are you able to help me form the regression model in a matrix form?

Comment: The coefficients can be estimated by $b=(X'X)^{-1}X'y$